# Python OpenCV returns wrong FPS

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I recorded 1 minute video using my webcam and then I used that video in a python program and checked the frame rate per second using opencv, but it returned false fps. It returned  1000 fps and 60883 total frames. I used following code to find above two.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
frames_per_sec = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)  
total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
```

While total number of frames correctly read by the following statement were around 1800.

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Now how do I correctly find fps of a video file recorded through webcam in python?